hfe value of transistor
EXPLANATION
I have difficulty interpreting the hfe value.
For example, the hfe table and graph of the 2N3055 npn transistor are given below.
I know that it is wrong to choose a specific hfe value because the hfe value can change due to factors such as production, environment etc., so the manufacturer gives us a guarantee between 20 and 70 as in this case. so that we can know worst case scenario etc. isn't it ?
The hfe between 20 and 70 is valid under the given conditions which are Ic=4A, Vce=4V.
QUESTION
Let say I want to follow Ic=0.5A in the graph @25 degree. This corresponds to hfe=100 approximately. But we said that choosing a specific hfe value is not correct so how can I describe a range as in the case of hfe between 20 and 70 ?

Source: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3055-d.pdf

Source: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3055-d.pdf

Every good transistor circuit design uses a circuit principle that is only slightly sensitive to hfe variations/uncertainties. Key point: Negative feedback.

The graph in the data sheet for hFE at 4 amps collector current is a typical value. Below, I've added green dots to show the upper (70) and lower (20) limit and, the red line that corresponds to a hFE of around 35: -

So, do the same at 0.5 amps and the spread will be roughly the same. It looks like a hFE of typically 120 and there should be corresponding upper and lower limits associated with that point. The lower hFE point will be about 80 (or maybe 70) by my rough reckoning.

How did you find the 80, what do you mean by the spread will be same ? @Andy aka

@Mhan the green dots are the outliers according to the numbers in the data sheet. The typical value is 35 (mid range). Now, keeping those ratios (outlier to mid), move them to align with 0.5 amps. The lower outlier will be about 80 (or maybe 70). Basically whatever is the result of 120*20/35.

I have no physical explanation, but using the same relative tolerance (-40/+100%) worked for me most of the time.
Because we like facts, I took 12 samples of 2N3055 from my museum, collected over 45+ years, and measured the DC gain at Vce = 4.0 V and Ic = 0.5 A.
One alien with hFE = 277 was a surprise, the others fit in the expected range.
This is the sorted result, hFE vs. item:

